# Angular sort by name incorrect

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I don't understand why sorting by name in ng-repeat is incorrect. The order starts out correct but then Holland is placed on the wrong order:

```
<div class="row">
  <div ng-if="region.checked && region.countCountries > 0" ng-repeat="region in vm.selectedRegions track by region.id" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 padding-left-0">
    <strong class="region-title">{{ 'locales.region.' + region.name | translate }}</strong>
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-if="($index == 0)" ng-repeat="country in region.countries track by $index" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 padding-left-0">
        <div ng-if="country.selected && ($index < region.countries.length/2)" ng-repeat="country in region.countries | orderBy: 'name' track by country.id">
          <span class="fa fa-circle"></span>
          <span translate="{{ 'locales.country.' + country.isoCode | translate }}"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-if="($index == vm.Math.ceil(region.countries.length/2))" ng-repeat="country in region.countries track by $index" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 padding-left-0">
        <div ng-if="country.selected && ($index >= region.countries.length/2)" ng-repeat="country in region.countries | orderBy: 'name' track by country.id">
          <span class="fa fa-circle"></span>
          <span translate="{{ 'locales.country.' + country.isoCode | translate }}"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Austria
 Belgium
 Bulgaria
 Denmark
 Finland
 France
 Germany
 Greece
 Hungary
 Ireland
 Israel
 Italy
 Holland
 Norway
 Poland
 Portugal
 Romania
 Spain
 Sweden
 Switzerland
 Turkey
 United Kingdom

Comment: maybe name stored as "Netherlands" and then `isoCode` translated as "Holland"?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "Austria Belgium Bulgaria Denmark Finland France Germany Greece Hungary Ireland Israel Italy" are in your first ng-repeat and  "Holland Norway Poland Portugal Romania Spain Sweden Switzerland Turkey United Kingdom" in the second ng-repeat.